# How to detected a nested Preference Screen has been loaded?

Tags: android

I need to set an event listener for a custom Preference that lives inside a nested PreferenceScreen.

My custom preference is a special checkbox to auto-select/unselect a bunch of CheckBoxPreferences, however, if I try to setup the event listener before the PreferenceScreen is clicked and shown, I can't get a reference to the checkbox I want to set my click listener on.

I can't seem to find a method to act upon which is invoked only when the nested preference screen is shown. I tried doing .getDialog() and to play with its listeners, but again, I get a null reference until the nested PreferenceScreen is actually displayed.

Comment: Why dont you post the .xml file?

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of any preference just call getDefaultSharedPreferences(). You don't need a callback. Just load the value set by the checkbox.

Comment: I don't need the value, I needed to set a UI callback and automatically alter the other ones when interacting with it. I found a work around that didn't require me to know exactly when the screen had been refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to this issue was to define the UI listener of my custom preference in its source code after its inner components had been inflated (in the `protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent)` method), not on the Settings Activity as I kept getting a null reference since it was too early to get a hold of it and I couldn't find a way to detect when the nested preference screen was loaded.